# lubridate: Parsing dates of the form '27.10.2013 02A:00' (daylight savings time)

Tags: r, datetime, timezone, lubridate

I am trying to parse strings of the form `25.10.2013 17:30` (the timezone is CET/CEST but this is not specified in the strings themselves) as POSIXct using lubridates `dmy_hm(..., tz = 'Europe/Brussels')` function.

I have the problem that after parsing, there are duplicate values on the day CEST switches to CET (the clock jumps one hour back). The cause seems to be the way this shift is indicated in my data: `02A:00` for 2 o'clock CEST and `02B:00` 2 o'clock CET, which is one hour later. `dmy_hm(..., tz = 'Europe/Brussels')` interprets both as CET.

Minimal working example:

```
> library(lubridate)

> times = c("27.10.2013 01:00", "27.10.2013 02A:00",
            "27.10.2013 02B:00", "27.10.2013 03:00")

> times = dmy_hm(times, tz = "Europe/Brussels")

> times
[1] "2013-10-27 01:00:00 CEST" "2013-10-27 02:00:00 CET"
[3] "2013-10-27 02:00:00 CET"  "2013-10-27 03:00:00 CET"
```

My question is: What would be the best way to fix the "wrong" dates?

I tried to use `which(duplicated(times))` to find the indices of the duplicate values and remove one hour from the "wrong" values, however there seems to be another problem:

```
> times[2] - hours(1)
[1] "2013-10-27 01:00:00 CEST"
```

Why does removing one hour from '"2013-10-27 02:00:00 CET"' bring me to '"2013-10-27 01:00:00 CEST"'? Isn't that a jump of two hours? I would expect to land at '"2013-10-27 02:00:00 CEST"'.

---

**EDIT:** The last part is a know issue (see https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/498). The solution is to use `dhours()` instead of `hours()`

```
> times[2] - dhours(1)
[1] "2013-10-27 02:00:00 CEST"
```